# Zend Portlet Kind of a Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-layout

I am using Zend Framework. Want to make a portlet kind of view, which is like each div is generated by a different controller/view pair.

Like the layout -

```
<div id="news">
   <?php echo $this->layout()->news; ?> -- calls news/recent
</div>
<div id="blogs">
   <?php echo $this->layout()->blogs; ?> -- calls blogs/recent
</div>
```

First I thought I would get it done by Action Stack, but later I found out that was not the right way to do it.

What are the other ways to achieve the same result? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could use [**Views Helpers**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) : create one helper for each one of your portlets.

Comment: @Nandini Do yourself a favor and **[don't use the ActionView Helper](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/)**.

Answer (score 2):

Nandini, I think you might be better off using Action Helpers.  This tutorial from Matthew Weier O'Phinney explains why, http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html.